# Optimize code in Django - view ManyToMany as matrix

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to show user group permissions in Django and show them in a "Drupal" style like a matrix. It works, but it takes too long to make the query and paint it in the template. Is there some way to improve my code?
view img 
[up(accomplished),down(views and template.html)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AunS.png)

views :

```
def GroupPermissionsView(request):

    title = "Groups Permissions"
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    permissions = Permission.objects.all()

    context = Context({
        'title': title,
        'groups': groups,
        'permissions': permissions,
    })
    return render(
        request,
        'forms_permissions.html',
        context
    )
```

template:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-inverse table-responsive table-bordered">

  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Permission</th>
            {% for group in groups %}
                <th>{{ group.name }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
        {% for permission in permissions %}
        <tr>
        <td><b>{{permission.name}}<b></td>
        {% for group in groups %}
             {% if permission in group.permissions.all %}
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked"></input></td>
            {% else %}
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ></input></td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How many groups and permissions do you have?

Comment: groups 4 pemissions more 200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was that you run more than 4 * 200 queries, one query for every combination or rows and columns (permissions and groups). It is useful to get them all by one query. It is however not easy because the intermediate model of `ManyToMany` relationship between `Permission` and `Group` models is not explicit in `django.contrib.auth.models`. You can get that model by [**`Model._meta API`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/meta/#model-meta-field-api):

```
>>> GroupPermissions = Permission._meta.get_field('group').through
>>> GroupPermissions
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group_permissions'>
>>> GroupPermissions._meta.db_table  # the table that you use in the raw query
'auth_group_permissions'
```

Put it all together. Prefer a longer view and simple template:

update the **view**:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

GroupPermissions = Permission._meta.get_field('group').through
groups = Group.objects.all()
permissions = Permission.objects.all()
permission_group_set = set()
for x in GroupPermissions.objects.all():
    permission_group_set.add((x.permission_id, x.group_id))
# row title and cells for every permission
permission_group_table = OrderedDict([
    (permission, [(permission.id, group.id) in permission_group_set for group in groups])
    for permission in permissions
])

context = Context({
    'title': title,
    'groups': groups,
    'permission_group_table': permission_group_table,
})
```

update the **template**

```
{% for permission, cells in permission_group_table.items %}
    <tr><td><b>{{permission.name}}<b></td>
    {% for cell in cells %}
        {% if cell %}
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" checked="checked"></input></td>
        {% else %}
            <td><input type="checkbox" ></input></td>
        {%  endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Brother thank you very much
I tried it and it works,
Thanks for helping and not letting die in the attempt and less a beginner

Comment: If you agree I will edit your question to be clear and more useful for other people. That is usually your (OP - original poster) added value to get the answer for free though not out of work. Look at edit history, maybe you prefer somewhere the original wording.

Comment: A [simpler solution of duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45900450/448474)