# How to perform inner join in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, inner-join

Taking the sentence:
`select * from auth_permission left join 
auth_group_permissions on (auth_group_permissions.permission_id = auth_permission.id)`
How can i do in django with queryset i do not understand how the inner join works in querysets

in models of default django auth

I've done this:

```
permiso = Permission.objects.all().select_related()
...: for x in permiso:
...:     print(x.group_set.all().query)
```

and see in each loop:

```
SELECT "auth_group"."id", "auth_group"."name" FROM "auth_group" INNER JOIN "auth_group_permissions" ON ("auth_group"."id" = "auth_group_permissions"."group_id") WHERE "auth_group_permissions"."permission_id" = 1255
```

Comment: You don't join in Django, Django joins for you. So please add your model(s) and explain what you are trying to archive.

Comment: I'm trying the Permission and Groups model to get all the permissions of those permissions to get the groups that have each permission
I have more or less 4 groups and more than 200 permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve all group elements and permission by [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
permissions = Permission.objects.prefetch_related('group_set').all()
for perm in permissions:
   group = perm.group_set.all()
```

Comment: @NEFEGAGO: It is usually recommended not to ask similar [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45889424/optimize-code-in-django-view-manytomany-as-matrix) and and to improve the original if it would not impair existing answer. This solution is however more Pythonic, simpler than mine and even so effective by minimal number of SQLs.

Answer (score -1):

When developing in Django you usually don't think about the SQL query you want to perform. In your case if you take a look at the [model definitions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/models/) of the auth app, you will se that the `Group` model has a `permissions` field of type [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Even if the field is defined in the `Group` model you can also do it in the reverse order (check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/)). So, in order to list all the permissions and for each one indicate in what groups they are, you can do something like:

```
for perm in Permission.objects.all():
    groups = perm.group_set.all()
    # Do something with groups
```

Comment: But the problem is that the query becomes too slow when I want to render it in a template